# Laravel not getting the APP_URL parameter when we try to use url function inside the blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, .env, laravel-config

I'm facing a weird situation, just look at the following code in a blade file, and the output of it

##### Blade

```html
{{ url('xero_invoice_authorised') }}</br>
config app url - {{ config('app.url') }}</br>
env app url - {{ env('APP_URL') }}
```

##### Output

```
http://xxxx/xero_invoice_authorised
config app url - https://xxxx/
env app url - https://xxxx/
```

`url()` is returning the URL as `http:` but it should be `https:`.

The system is inside a docker container.

I have run all commands to clear the cache, view, routes, and even ran `optimize` command.

Can anyone suggest to me what's wrong with my configuration? or any method to rectify this issue?

I need `{{ url('') }}` to return the `APP_URL` in the `.env` file.

Answer (score 2):

There is no error at all, it is working as expected.

First of all, never use `env()` outside the `config` folder, because when you run `php artisan optimize` or `php artisan config:cache`, `env()` will always return `null`. More info in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-env). I understand if this is just a test, but have it always in mind.

Second, `url()` will ALWAYS return `http` instead of `https`. You have to use `secure_url()` if you want `https`. Check the documentation for [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-url) and [`secure_url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-secure-url).

Third, just to show you how it works, here is the official source code of [`url()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/830efbeeb815a5f1558433b673a58b0ddcbdc750/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L968-L974), the [`UrlGenerator`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/830efbeeb815a5f1558433b673a58b0ddcbdc750/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L203-L227) is the one processing the `http://` or `https://`, you can try debugging what it is reading and checking why it is using insecure instead of the other one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and giving the insight

Answer (score -1):

After different tryouts found a working method
I updated the AppServiceProvider with the following to force the HTTPS on production environment.
File :  app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
            if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
                URL::forceScheme('https');
            }
    }
```

Comment: Do not use `env` outside a config file, use `config`

Answer (score -1):

**Don't use env() anywhere except in your con fig files; once config has been cached, there will be nothing available from .env.**

If AMP is a third party service, then put the key into **config/services.php:**

**// config/services.php**

```
<?php

return [
    // ...

    'amp' => [
        'key' => env('AMP_KEY'),
    ],

],
```

**Then in the view:**

```
<meta name="amp_key" content="{{ config('services.amp.key') }}">
```